# How long can I use windows unactivated?

Tags: windows-8

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Windows 8 Activation Period](https://superuser.com/questions/496131/windows-8-activation-period)

I haven't activated my copy of windows 8 yet. 
how long can I use windows unactivated?
What will happen when the time expires?